# POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/customers 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using Laravel 6.2 and 2.5.17, When I submit new reply without body, I get error 422 (Unprocessable Entity) https://prnt.sc/psceiw

How to solve it ?

My API Controller:

```
<?php
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:customers',
            'phone' => 'required|numeric',
            'address' => 'required',
            'total' => 'required|numeric'
        ]);

        $customer = new Customer();
        $customer->name = $request->name;
        $customer->email = $request->email;
        $customer->phone = $request->phone;
        $customer->address = $request->address;
        $customer->total = $request->total;
        $customer->save();                      //save data 
        return new CustomerResource($customer);     // save and return
    }    
?>
```

My Main.js:

```
import PaginationComponent from './components/partial/PaginationComponent.vue'
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueProgressBar from 'vue-progressbar'
import Snotify, { SnotifyPosition } from 'vue-snotify'  // Import Snotify
import { Form, HasError, AlertError } from 'vform'   // Import vform

//  show window form                                                   
window.Vue = require('vue');
window.Form = Form

const SnotifyOptions = {
    toast: {
        position: SnotifyPosition.rightTop
    }
}

Vue.use(Snotify, SnotifyOptions);

const VueProgressBarOptions = {
    color: '#50d37a',
    failedColor: '#874b4b',
    thickness: '5px',
    transition: {
        speed: '0.2s',
        opacity: '0.6s',
        termination: 300
    },
    autoRevert: true,
    location: 'top',
    inverse: false
}

Vue.use(VueProgressBar, VueProgressBarOptions)

Vue.component('customer-component', require('./components/CustomerComponent.vue').default)

Vue.component('pagination', PaginationComponent)

// vform
Vue.component(HasError.name, HasError)
Vue.component(AlertError.name, AlertError)

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});

// And componentsVue.vue: 
<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return{
                query: '',
                queryFeild: 'name',
                customers: [],
                form : new Form({
                    id : '',
                    name: '',
                    email: '',
                    phone: '',
                    address: '',
                    total: '',
                }),
                pagination:{
                    current_page: 1,
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            query:function (newQ, old) {
                if (newQ === '') {
                    this.getData();
                }
                else{
                    // console.log(newQ) // to check saerch data
                    this.searchData()
                }
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
            this.getData();
        },
        methods: {
            getData(){  
                this.$Progress.start()
                axios.get('/api/customers?page='+this.pagination.current_page)
                .then(response =>  {
                    this.customers = response.data.data
                    this.pagination = response.data.meta
                    this.$Progress.finish()
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    console.log(e)
                    this.$Progress.fail()
                })
            },
            searchData(){
                this.$Progress.start()
                axios.get('/api/search/customers/'+this.queryFeild+'/'+this.query+'?page='+this.pagination.current_page)
                .then(response => {
                    this.customers = response.data.data
                    this.pagination = response.data.meta
                    this.$Progress.finish()
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    console.log(e)
                    this.$Progress.fail()
                })
            },
            reload(){
                this.getData()
                this.query = ''
                this.queryFeild = 'name'
                this.$snotify.success('Data Successfully Refresh','Success')
            },
            create(){    // show modal to add customer
                this.form.reset()
                this.form.clear()
                $('#customerModal').modal('show')
            },
            store(){   // data store/insert to add customer
                this.$Progress.start()
                this.form.busy = true
                this.form.post('/api/customers')
                .then(response => {
                    this.getData()
                    $('#customerModal').modal('hide')
                    if (this.form.successful) 
                    {
                        this.$Progress.finish()
                        this.$snotify.success('Customer Successfully Saved','Success')
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.$Progress.fail()
                        this.snotify.error("Ops! Something went wrong try again leter", "Error")
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.$Progress.fail()
                    if(error.code == 422){
                        console.log(error.data)
                    }
                    // console.log(e)
                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That error is thrown when your request fails validation. You have to check which of your values is invalid

Comment: The response means one or more of the input values failed validation. You can use developer tools on the browser to see the error message, or simply log the input just before validation to see what's missing or incorrect

Comment: Thank you, but i'm not not sure, where are wrong. This is input fields:  https://prnt.sc/psiujg

input fields, controller fields and api data fields same as, so any wrong